# What is the difference between "mobiliario" and "mueble(s)"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, sustantivos, diferencias-entre-palabras

The first word I learned for "furniture" in Spanish was "mueble(s)."  Since then, I've been exposed to a lot more Spanish and one thing I've noticed is that there is this other word for furniture — mobiliario.  Apart from the fact that *muebles* is much more frequent than *mobiliario*, are there any differences in usage between these two words or are they relatively interchangeable?

Are there any situations in which one would sound odd?  For example, if I were to say, "Vamos a comprar mobiliario nuevo," would it sound odd?  Though I could come to some conclusions based on things such as number of web pages I might be able to find with each, I'd appreciate a native Spanish speaker's perspective on the usage of these two words (or any other words closely related to them).

---

La primera palabra que aprendí para "furniture" en español fue "mueble/s".  Desde entonces, he estado expuesto a mucho más español y una de las cosas que he notado es que hay esta otra palabra para "furniture" — *mobiliario*.  Aparte del hecho de que *muebles* es mucho más frecuente que *mobiliario*, ¿hay alguna diferencia en uso entre las dos palabras?  ¿O son completamente intercambiables?

¿Hay algunas situaciones en que una de estas palabras pueda sonar extraña?  Por ejemplo, si dijera "Vamos a comprar mobiliario nuevo", ¿sonaría raro?  Aunque podría llegar a algunas conclusiones basados en cosas como la cantidad de páginas web que se encuentra por varias combinaciones de expresión, preferiría tener la perspectiva de un/-a hispanohablante en el uso de estas dos palabras (o otras similares en significado).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Mobiliario* is a collective noun; it corresponds well with English "furniture". *Mueble* is a countable noun; it means "piece of furniture". Therefore you can say either

1. *Vamos a comprar muebles nuevos.*
2. *Vamos a comprar mobiliario nuevo.*

The difference between 1 and 2 is that when you say *muebles* in such a context it can be understood that you're going to buy **some** new pieces of furniture, but if you say *mobiliario* it suggests more like you're renovating **all** of your furniture. Similarly, suppose you say

1. *No me gustan nada estos muebles.*
2. *No me gusta nada este mobiliario.*

Here the difference is that in 1, someone could ask, well, **which ones** don't you like specifically? But in 2 it really sounds like you don't like any of the pieces of furniture, or maybe even the general style of it.

Most times in real life you'll use *mueble(s)*. You'll only use *mobiliario* for special situations; it's not a rare word per se, but it's associated with commercial transactions, interior decoration, etc. You don't go to a friend's new house and praise their *mobiliario*, but their *muebles*.

Comment: Notice that "mobiliario" sometimes is accompanied by the adjective "completo", indicating that you can have an uncompleted mobiliario. The definition shown in the DRAE does not specify how complete is the set. Leaving that aside, great answer, as usual.

Comment: Also I can see no difference between "No me gustan estos muebles" y "No me gusta este mobiliario"

Comment: @RubioRic Yes, *mobiliario* doesn't have to mean all of the furniture; it only suggests it a little more than just saying *muebles*.

Comment: But you have highlighted "all" in your example. A little more is a bit undetermined, isn't it?

Comment: As a native Spanish (iberian) speaker, I feel this answer captures the difference between the two words perfectly.

Comment: @Nubarke I disagree with you from the same Iberia. :-)

Comment: I did write "all", but I wrote "it suggests" before that. I don't know how else to express the idea.

Comment: I am pleasantly surprised to see that this has already met with so many upvotes.  I am also pleasantly surprised to see not only one, but two outstanding answers to this question.  It's a tough call, but due to the number of votes for pablodf76's answer and how many times in the past he has provided clear, solid information that goes above and beyond without being redundant or excessive, I award the green check mark to Pablo.

Answer (score 6):

**Practically there is no difference for a native speaker between those terms**. Taking into account that you employ the plural in **muebles**.

**Mobiliario** sounds a **bit more formal** and it tends to be used to refer furniture located in an office or some kind of business, but it's also valid for a family home.

You can check the definitions for both terms in the DRAE.

> [**mueble**](https://dle.rae.es/mueble)
>   2. m. Cada uno de los enseres movibles que sirven para los usos necesarios o para decorar casas, oficinas y todo género de locales.

which essentially match the definition provided in the Cambridge Dictionary for [furniture](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/furniture)

> things such as chairs, tables, beds, cupboards, etc. that are put into
>   a house or other building to make it suitable and comfortable for
>   living or working in

On the other hand, we got

> **[mobiliario](https://dle.rae.es/mobiliario)**
>   2. m. **Set of muebles** in a house.
>
> **mobiliario urbano**
>
> 1. m. Set of elements provided by City Halls in order to service their neighborhoods like, seats, paper bins, marquees, etc.

Notice the parts that I've highlighted. Mobiliario is a set of muebles, but it doesn't mean implicitly a FULL COMPLETE SET. The diference between mobiliario and muebles (plural), if it exists, must be explicitly stated. On the other hand, there is no such thing as "muebles urbanos", that's the reason that I've quoted that part too.

After interchanging opinions with Lambie, I don't agree with one of the examples provided by Pablo. These two sentences are indistinguishable in Spanish:

> No me gustan estos muebles
>   No me gusta este mobiliario

---

Realmente no hay mucha diferencia para un hispanohablante entre los dos términos.
**Mobiliario** suena un poco más formal y suele emplearse más para referirse a los **muebles de una oficina o un negocio**, pero también es válido para un hogar particular.

Puedes contrastar las definiciones de ambos términos que aparecen en el DRAE.

> [**mueble**](https://dle.rae.es/mueble)
>   2. m. Cada uno de los enseres movibles que sirven para los usos necesarios o para decorar casas, oficinas y todo género de locales.
>
> **[mobiliario](https://dle.rae.es/mobiliario)**
>   2. m. **Conjunto de muebles** de una casa.
>
> **mobiliario urbano**
>
> 1. m. Conjunto de instalaciones facilitadas por los ayuntamientos para el servicio del vecindario, como bancos, papeleras, marquesinas, etc.

Presta atención a las partes que he destacado en negrita. Mobiliario es un conjunto de muebles, pero no significa implicitamente TODOS los muebles. La diferencia, si existe, entre mobiliario y muebles en plural debe indicarse explícitamente. Por otro lado no existe el término "muebles urbanos", por eso he querido destacar esa acepción concreta.

Despues de intercambiar opiniones con Lambie, me doy cuenta de que no estoy de acuerdo con uno de los ejemplos aportados por Pablo. Estas dos frases son prácticamente indistinguibles en español:

> No me gustan estos muebles
>   No me gusta este mobiliario

Comment: piece of furniture = mueble versus furniture, mobilario

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I've already seen Pablo's answer, thanks. I've compared the terms directly in Spanish: mueble vs mobiliario. That's what OP was asking, she was not asking for translation. Do you have the term "urban furniture" in English?

Comment: He actually uses it awkwardly. We would not normally say: you don't like any of the pieces of furniture. We would use furniture there. I bought a new piece of furniture for the living room, for example.

Comment: @Lambie I don't agree with either of you. "No me gustan estos muebles" and "No me gusta este mobiliario" are practically indistinguishable. In both cases, in Spanish, you can ask "¿No te gusta ninguno?"